# Binary problem : how to find integer B conforms to integer A

Tags: algorithm, binary, operation

I want to write an algorithm (in Python), that get all the integers that are conforms to an another integer B, written in binary.

When A is conforms to B, it means that in all positions where B has bits set to 1, A has corresponding bits set to 1.

By example :
If we have 1001, the confoms numbers are : 1111, 1011, 1101;

We can assume that the solution should work with very large numbers (so has to be quite efficient).

I have thought about many solutions about doing some binary operations but I cannot get a complete solution.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You should calculate all permutations. You can use from itertools import permutations library to calculate.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I create a solution without using any libray ? Like making my "own" all permutations algorithm in Python ?

Comment: Given any integer `x`, the next higher integer conforming to `T` is `(x+1) | T`

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your example:
An integer with `z` zero bits has `2**z` conforming integers. We can subtract one, because one of these is the integer itself.

Accordingly, your algorithm has to count from `1` to `2**z` and replace the `z` zero bits in the original integer by the `z` bits of your counter.

In python, you can use [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) to test or change bit positions within an integer.

**Examples for bitwise operations:**

`x & 1` returns `1`, if the least-significant bit is set. Otherwise `0`

`x = x | 4` will set the 3rd bit corresponding to `4`

**Sketch of your algorithm:**

```
1.  Loop through the integer to find and count the zero bits
2.  Loop from 1 to 2**z
    Inner loop: Scan the z bits of the counter
        Transfer the bits to a copy of the original integer
    Record/output the resulting conformant integer
```